# How to make cinnamon show active programms with bars

Tags: fedora, cinnamon

I have an installation of `f30` in which I've installed `Cinnamon`.

When running a program instead of having it displayed with bars (or text next to the icon) as shown for instance [image]

I get the following

[image]

Any idea on how to make the active programms look like bars in cinnamon?

Comment: what do you mean by `bars`? ... are you talking about having text next to the icon?

Comment: @jsotola : Thank you very much for your comment. Yes, this is exactly what I mean!

Comment: is there a setting for that? ... show icons and text?

Comment: @jsotola : I  haven't found anything like that. Any idea?

Comment: i don't have a linux computer available right now ... i do remember that the icons are inside a container, or some kind of an app .... check for configuration of the container

Comment: @jsotola : Thanks for the suggestion. I had a look, but I couldn't find anything in the settings..